# Hide helptext() according to if condition in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(

             ),

             mainPanel(
               wellPanel(
                 tags$style(type="text/css",
                            ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                            ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                 ),
                 uiOutput("c1"),
                 uiOutput("num8"),
                 uiOutput("help1")

               )



             )
           )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$c1<-renderUI({
    checkboxInput("ch1", 
                  h5("Person ID"), value = FALSE)
  })

  output$num8<-renderUI({
    if(input$ch1==T){
      textInput("nm8", 
                h6("Column"), 
                value = 1)
    }
    else{
      output$help1<-renderUI({
        helpText("Click Person ID")
      }) 
    }

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I want to achieve is hide the helptext "Click Person ID" when the tickbox is clicked. I have used an if condition for this but while the numeric input is hidden when it has to the helptext is always there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a `renderUI()` wrapped in a `renderUI()`. That might get you into trouble. You could seperate them instead, then it will work.

```
  output$num8<-renderUI({
    if(input$ch1 == TRUE){
      textInput("nm8", 
                h6("Column"), 
                value = 1)
    }
  })

  output$help1<-renderUI({
    if(input$ch1 == FALSE){
      helpText("Click Person ID")
    } 
  })
```

Full code will read:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(

             ),

             mainPanel(
               wellPanel(
                 tags$style(type="text/css",
                            ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                            ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                 ),
                 uiOutput("c1"),
                 uiOutput("num8"),
                 uiOutput("help1")

               )
             )
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$c1<-renderUI({
    checkboxInput("ch1", 
                  h5("Person ID"), value = FALSE)
  })

  output$num8<-renderUI({
    if(input$ch1 == TRUE){
      textInput("nm8", 
                h6("Column"), 
                value = 1)
    }
  })

  output$help1<-renderUI({
    if(input$ch1 == FALSE){
      helpText("Click Person ID")
    } 
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```